# Git Pointers and blobs

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new to distributed version control and i understand that unchanged files in git commits aren't blobbed, but are simply stored as pointers to the last changed file,

but...

Does the pointer point to the last commit, or to the last commit where the file was changed?

Ie if i have 10 commits, but index.html hasn't changed since the first commit, does the pointer in commit 10 point to the file in the first commit, or does it point to the pointer in commit 9, which points to commit 8 etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

It points to the file (blob) itself, without going through another commit. The linkage is like this: commit -> tree -> (tree ...) -> blob.